# URL plus string

Tags: java, android

How can i convert

```
String firebase = ("http// blah blah.com");
```

The users will input there account from eedittex.

```
String account = string.valueof(AAcount.getText().tostring);
String url = fribase + account;
```

Into url? Is it possible?.

Comment: can you please provide a code where you have a difficulty

Answer (score 0):

Simply do:

```
String url = fribase + account;
URL myUrl = new URL(url);
```

Comment: Do i have to sorround it with catch?.

Comment: @AlxBau yes you have to wrap around try catch. What is the value of `url` string?

Comment: It should be getting http://myproject.firebaseio.com/myaccount@gmail.com

Comment: Do it have to remove @gmail.com from the account to make it work?

Comment: @AlxBau Yes. It will create proper URL but not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I was trying to add the score and account from the user into firebase database ,the thing is im not using auth type from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

String firebase = ("http// blah blah.com");
String myUrl = fribase + "/" + account;